# Oracle APEX article creation like Blog

Tags: sql, oracle, web, oracle-apex

I am gaining competence on Oracle APEX and I am having fun.  I want to make a website for an association with an "article" section.  Thus the Admin, thanks to a form, will be able to create articles with an image (so far no worries).

My problem is that instead of creating a "card" by articles it would be much better to create a page for SEO, I think that so far I am on the right track.  Do you know how you can help me create a form that creates pages and articles?  Do you have the resources to do this?

Thanks in advance, nice day

Comment: This is old, but someone built similar many years ago http://www.apexninjas.com/blog/blog-platform/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Yes after posting the article I saw ninja apex. It's great but as you said it's a bit old. thanks a lot for your answer